# reverse function for label encoder resulted class

Tags: transform, reverse, prediction, label-encoding

I have used the label encoder for transforming a column say 'A' of dataset.Let say that new column is termed as 'B'.Now I have used a regression algorithm to predict the column 'B'.But I need a predicted class in 'A' form only.I am using the reverse transform function for doing so but it is giving error after using the the reverse transform function on the predicted data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an object created when we fit the label encoder.
So can use object_name.inverse_transform(prediction_test).